# WPF Dependency Property

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, properties, dependencies

I'm struggling to get my head around dependency properties in WPF, maybe because the use case I'm looking for is very specific and not well documented.

What I have is a custom control that looks like this (please do ignore all the terrible code, it is temporary!):

```
<UserControl x:Class="HydroAccessory.Controls.FillGraph"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:HydroAccessory.Controls"
         mc:Ignorable="d"
         SizeChanged="FillGraph_SizeChanged"
         d:DesignHeight="200" d:DesignWidth="300">
<Grid>

    <TextBlock x:Name="PercentageTB" Text="Fill Percentage: 0%" />

</Grid>
```

I call it inside my main window like this:

```
<controls:FillGraph x:Name="HydroModel" />
```

and the code inside the control is as follows:

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace HydroAccessory.Controls
{
public partial class FillGraph : UserControl
{
    private float percentage;
    public float Percentage
    {
        get
        {
            return percentage;
        }
        set
        {
            percentage = value;
            PercentageTB.Text = String.Format("Fill Percentage: {0}", percentage.ToString() + "%");
        }
    }

    public FillGraph()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
}
```

All that I want to be able to do is say in my custom control call in the main window:

```
<controls:FillGraph x:Name="HydroModel" Percentage="{Binding FillPercentage}" />
```

(Where FillPercentage is something in another script that you don't need to worry about).
The control will be expanded, so it needs to stay as a custom control.
I understand I may need dependency properties, but after trying many different ways I cannot figure out how to do this seemingly simple task. Help is appreciated.

Comment: You need to actually make a dependency property. What don't you understand?

Comment: `Percentage` is currently a normal property. Simply make it [dependency property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/dependency-properties-overview).

Comment: propdp snippet should help you

Comment: The code I listed was to show what I wanted to add the dependency property to - I had tested many different dependency property methods (none of which worked for me), so I assumed I was setting up the property incorrectly - which is why I left it blank! The answer has worked for me though, thanks for the help

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There isn't a dependency property in your code.

This is a dependency property:

```
public partial class FillGraph : UserControl
{
    public FillGraph()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public float Percentage
    {
        get { return (float)GetValue(PercentageProperty); }
        set { SetValue(PercentageProperty, value); }
    }

    //  Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Percentage.  This 
    //  enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty PercentageProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Percentage", typeof(float), 
                typeof(FillGraph), new PropertyMetadata(0.0f));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer - it turns out it was a variety of things going wrong, one being as you mentioned setting the property metadata to not a float, and others being not binding the textblock inside the control to the script (which just complicated things even though it would've worked). The answer posted did indeed work for me - Thanks!

Comment: What just complicated things?

Comment: No need to worry about it, I clipped some code out for ease of reading and it caused some issues - all working now though!